# Campo desabilitado se condição for verdade

Tags: angular

Tenho uma view de edição de valor e parcelas...
Nessa view tenho 2 campos, 1 botão e uma lista (onde posso editar a linha para que o status fique como paga):

[image]

Nesta lista contem uma coluna status, se houver pelo menos um item com status pago, colocar disabled para os campos e botão para impedir o recalculo dessas parcelas. Caso nao haja nenhum status pago, permitir recalcular as parcelas e/ou mudar o valor.

Eu criei uma propriedade `parcelasPagas` no `component.ts` com o valor de `false`, faço a verificação pra transformar ele em `true` caso haja algum pago.

Sou novo com angular, não sei o que fazer. Tentei com o `ngIf` porem ele serve para mostrar e esconder né, mas o disabled não consegui fazer...

Foi isso que eu tentei:

```
<div class="card color-bordered-table info-bordered-table" *ngIf="!parcelasPagas">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a propriadade disabel nos componentes colocando essa propriedade no input

```
[disabled]="parcelasPagas"
```